# ChartJs beforeDraw method not getting called in release build

Tags: javascript, dart, chart.js, angular-dart, chartjs-2.6.0

I am developing a web app using angular dart.

I am using ChartJs library to render charts.

I am using beforeDraw plugin to do some stuff with my chart.

beforeDraw is successfully getting executed in debug build.
(pub run build_runner build --output build)

But when I used the release build
(pub run build_runner build --output build --release),
beforeDraw is not getting called.

This is where I register the plugin:

```
    final plugin = PluginServiceRegistrationOptions(beforeDraw: beforeDraw);
    Chart.pluginService.register(plugin);
    _renderChart();
```

This is where I have defined beforeDraw:

```
  void beforeDraw(Chart chart, String easing) {
    print('inside beforeDraw');
  }
```

Why is it not getting executed in release build?

I tried this:

```
final plugin = PluginServiceRegistrationOptions(beforeDraw: allowInterop(beforeDraw));
```

In browser console, it showed this exception:

```
Uncaught NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call'
Receiver: Closure 'a1Y' of Instance of 'minified:eP'
Arguments: [Instance of 'kE', 0.06499308566807294, Instance of 'minified:Of']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your function in the [allowInterop](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-js/allowInterop.html) function

Comment: I have added the code and the error I got in the question.